# Server code generation from WSDL publishes different output

Tags: c#, server, wsdl

I have an WSDL with external .xsd files referenced inside that was given to me by my client. Now my job is to create a web service server in Visual Studio using C#. I tried using wsdl.exe and svcutil.exe to generate code.

```
wsdl Input.wsdl XSD1.xsd XSD2.xsd XSD3.xsd /l:CS /serverInterface
svcutil Input.wsdl XSD1.xsd XSD2.xsd XSD3.xsd /sc
```

I did that successfully but now here comes the issue.

My server when using ?wsdl posts different WSDL that I used for generation. And now when I try to send a request using original WSDL my server doesn't except it. I search all over this forum but unfortunately nothing worked for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your custom WSDL by using the `<serviceMetadata externalMetadataLocation=""/>` attribute in your `<behaviour>` element.

i.e.

```
<behaviors>  
  <serviceBehaviors>  
    <behavior name="YourServiceBehavior">  
      <serviceMetadata externalMetadataLocation="path/YourWsdl.wsdl"/>  
    </behavior>  
  </serviceBehaviors>  
</behaviors>
```

path can be absolute or relative but you must also make sure that the child XSD files are in the correct relative location to where the WSDL imports them from.

Whether this fixes your second problem, I don't know but that's a separate issue to be resolved once you have the service using your custom WSDL.